# Can I access file name and file type by using File.Exists

Tags: c#, types, filenames, file-exists, file-access

`filepath` variable is coming over UDP socket. And after my codes are below:

```
string filename=null;
string filetype=null;
if (File.Exists(filepath)){
     filename=?????;
     filetype=????;
}
```

Can I access file name and file type?

Comment: Programming language should go in *tags*, not *titles*.

Comment: @crashmstr this is my second writing in stackoverflow. I'm learning, thanks to you :)

Comment: By "filetype" do you just want the extension?

Comment: [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @JamesThorpe filetype or extension like ".rar" , ".jpg", ".txt" etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
var f = new FileInfo(filepath);
filename = f.Name;
filetype = f.Extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string filename = null;
string filetype = null;
if (File.Exists(filepath)) {
    filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
    filetype = Path.GetExtension(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the filename and filetype using Path class.

```
filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath)
filetype = Path.GetExtension(filepath)
```